Caesar cipher shifts the letters in an alphabet list incorrectly
I'm following a course, where you write a caesar cipher. After doing the task myself with slightly different code (which worked), I have now tried to replicate the code exactly from the course, and it does not seem to work (ChatGPT says it should be working too)
If I choose to 'decode', type the letter 'C' and shift it by 2 (which will become -2), it correctly shows the letter 'a'.
But if i try to decode a full word, for example by choosing 'decode', writing 'khoor' and shifting by '3', it should show 'hello', but instead shows 'hklro'.
Here is the code:
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n").lower()
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

def caesar(encode_or_decode,original_text, shift_amount):
    output_text = ""
    for letter in original_text:
        if encode_or_decode == "decode":
            shift_amount *= -1
        shifted_position = alphabet.index(letter) + shift_amount
        shifted_position %= len(alphabet)
        output_text += alphabet[shifted_position]
    print(f"Here is the {encode_or_decode}d result: {output_text}")

caesar(original_text=text, shift_amount=shift, encode_or_decode=direction)

My input was
"decode", "khoor", "3"


"ChatGPT says it should be working too"—ChatGPT doesn't understand anything. It just takes a prompt and spits out a likely response.

You test encode_or_decode inside the for loop, and if its decode, you keep multiplying the shift_amount by -1 on each iteration, which causes the wrong result when decoding. Move the check outside the loop, and you should be fine:
def caesar(encode_or_decode,original_text, shift_amount):
    output_text = ""
    if encode_or_decode == "decode": # encode_or_decode check moved here
        shift_amount *= -1
    for letter in original_text:
        shifted_position = alphabet.index(letter) + shift_amount
        shifted_position %= len(alphabet)
        output_text += alphabet[shifted_position]
    print(f"Here is the {encode_or_decode}d result: {output_text}")


Ah! Thanks so much, you got it

@Gusm98, great! If this answered your question you can optionally accept it by clicking on the ✔️. This tells other users which answer worked best for you, marks your question as having been answered in the Stack Overflow database, and  rewards you and the answerer with reputation points.
